# How to handle PHP project code in docker container

Tags: docker, composer-php, docker-compose

I ran into kind of a hen-and-egg problem with my docker setup. In my `Dockerfile` I install nginx, php and the needed configurations. I also install composer there:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    nginx \
    nodejs \
    php7.0-fpm \
    php-intl \
    php-pgsql
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
COPY orocrm /etc/nginx/sites-available/
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-availabe/orocrm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/orocrm
CMD nginx
```

Now, the next step would be to actually install all dependencies in the project directory via composer. And this is where the trouble starts: As this is my development machine, I don't want to copy my local project files over to the docker container. Instead, I mounted it in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    ...
    volumes:
      - "./crm-application:/var/www/orocrm/"
```

I cannot put `composer install` in the Dockerfile, as the mounting of the directory (in my docker-compose file) is taking place *after* the Dockerfile is run.

What is the best solution here? Another option which comes to my mind is intially copying the files into the container and later on use a filewatcher to `scp` the changed files into the container. Not a nice solution, though.

**UPDATE** I would like to emphasize what my actual problem is: I am on my development machine and I want to continuously update the code and have the changes mirrored *instantly* withouth building the image once again. Therefore, `COPY` is not an option.

Comment: Try something like this: create a script to be used in the startup of the container (ex: `start.sh`, make it executable) which runs `composer install` and then `nginx`, and add it with `COPY start.sh /start.sh` and `CMD /start.sh` in the Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to copy your content in your container using the `COPY`command, like this

```
FROM ubuntu

COPY ./crm-application /var/www/orocrm/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    nginx \
    nodejs \
    php7.0-fpm \
    php-intl \
    php-pgsql

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/ && \
     composer install

COPY orocrm /etc/nginx/sites-available/

RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-availabe/orocrm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/orocrm

CMD nginx
```

Why? in this way you don't need to use docker-compose or another system. You're going to be able to run your single container.
Even if you want to use docker-compose, you're using a volume that allows you to update the code inside your container.

Notice that I've added `composer install` in the `Docker` because you've already the code inside the container at the moment of the build.

Regards,
Idir!

Comment: Thanks for your input, but as I stated above, I want to have the code continuously updated in the container. That's not possible by using `COPY` once in the build process.

Comment: Hi @Chrisissorry, of course, I gonna be updated since you're using docker-compose your code is gonna be updated but that doesn't mean that you cannot copy. 
Your container should have all that you need to run it, and then, as an additional point, you can sync your folder using docker-compose.

That's why `COPY` and `VOLUMES` are not exclusive.

See this example with docker-compose:

- https://github.com/docker/example-voting-app
- https://github.com/DataDog/docker-compose-example
- https://github.com/vegasbrianc/docker-compose-demo